# ubuntu: find all files changed at certain date

Tags: search, date, ubuntu

I would like to get list of all files changed at certain date (e.g. 11.1.2012) in Ubuntu.

```
find -mtime
```

works for days before, but I want files from exactly one day and want to do it more comfartable than by counting days back. Is there any way to do so?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a little trick. Use the *touch* command to create two files with a modification date that includes the date you're searching for.

Example:

> touch -t 201204080000 dummy1
>
> touch -t 201204082359 dummy2

then you can use *find* as follows:

> find /somedir/ ( -newer dummy1 -and ! -newer dummy2 )

This should work out well.

Comment: There's no need to create files! Just use `-newermt` instead of `-newer`: `find -newermt 2017-10-12`